# (Selenium) Running many firefox browser with less performance

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

So I want to run many Firefox Webbrowsers in background with Selenium.
I used already --headless to make the clients invisible but my question is if there is another thing that I can do to reduce my performance to open more browser, because if I try more than 30 Firefox client it crashes my PC.

I already looked for some solutions and I just found --no-startup-window but this didn't do anything.

So is there another thing that I can do to run over 50 or more Firefox browsers completely in background without killing my PC?

Comment: Why does it crash? How does it crash?

Comment: It crashed cause my PC cant run more than 30 Firefox brwosers, first its lagging and if there are starting to many browsers its crashing. Thats why Im asking if there is something how is can reduce this performance use like the browsers are doing there thing completely in background

Comment: But why is it lagging? Is it CPU? Is it RAM? Something else?